# Button created in Jquery can't apply function

Tags: jquery

I am generating a webpage purely out of jQuery. What is supposed to happen is that when I press the '+' button on the page, the function `add_timeline_element` is called to create a new group of elements. Instead I get an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Function.prototype.apply was called on [object
>   Object], which is a object and not a function

I'm not sure why this error is occurring. Like I said everything has been generated through Jquery, and I am attaching button's click and the function in the same as another button/function 'm'/`minimize_t_inject_container` and that other one works just fine.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/easilyBaffled/6pJVV/)**

**JS:**

```
$(function(){    
    function add_timeline_element(){
        var timeline_element = $('<ul />', {
            class: "timeline_element"
        });
            var section_1 = $("<li />");
            var section_2 = $("<li />");
                var button = $('<button />', {
                    text: '-',
                    class: "t_intect_button"
                    //click: function(){alert($(this).parent().parent().remove();}
                });
                var text_input = $('<input />', {
                    type: "text",
                    class: "t_text_area"
                });

                section_1.append(button);
                section_2.append(text_input);
            timeline_element.append(section_1);
            ti
            meline_element.append(section_2);
        $(".t_inject_container").append(timeline_element);
    }

    function minimize_t_inject_container(){
        $(".add_button").toggle();
    }

    function create_twitter_bar(){
        var table_container = $("<ul />", {
            class: "t_inject_container"
        });
            var row = $("<li />", { class: "t_inject_row" });
                var menu = $("<ul />", { class: "menu" });
                    var section_1 = $("<li />");
                    var section_2 = $("<li />");
                        var add_element_button = $("<button />", {
                            text: '+',
                            click: add_timeline_element,
                            class: "add_button t_intect_button"

                        });
                        var minimize_button = $("<button />", {
                            text: 'm',
                            click: minimize_t_inject_container,
                            class: "minimize_button t_intect_button"
                        });
                    section_1.append(add_element_button);
                    section_2.append(minimize_button);
                menu.append(section_1);
                menu.append(section_2);
            row.append(menu);
            table_container.append(row);
        $('body').append(table_container);
    }
    create_twitter_bar();
```

Comment: what is `section_1(button)` and `section_2(text_input)` supposed to be doing? I'm getting an error saying they're not functions (because they're not) when I click on the + button.

Comment: Well that was dumb of me thank you.

Comment: It's still in the fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `section_1(button);` `and section_2(text_input);`, and `section_1` and `section_2` are elements.  You are treating them as functions, which you cannot do.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
var button = $('<button />', {
                    text: '-',
                    class: "t_intect_button"
                }).on('click', function(){alert($(this).parent().parent().remove())});
```